# Magento Reviews - When do they get aggregated?

Tags: magento-1.7, database

Can somebody provide some insight for when reviews get put into the `rating_option_vote_aggregated` table?  I'm trying to filter through my reviews based on four stars or higher and I was looking to use the `percent_approved` column for joining up with the review table, however not all of the latest approved reviews are in the `rating_option_vote_aggregated` table.

Do we need to install some sort of post-review-approval code that calls `$review->aggregate()`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no magic code that automatically aggregates the review data for a client programmer — you need to call this method manually after a review object is created.  You can see this on the frontend at in the `postAction` method in

```
app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php
```

and in various methods on the backend

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/ReviewController.php
```

My guess would be there's one of two things happening.  The first is you have some custom code that's creating reviews manually, and failing to call `aggregate` correctly.

The second is there's a certain percentage of people who attempt to review a product, but because of server load or some other problem, the request fails halfway through such that

```
$review->setEntityId($review->getEntityIdByCode(Mage_Review_Model_Review::ENTITY_PRODUCT_CODE))
    ->setEntityPkValue($product->getId())
    ->setStatusId(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_PENDING)
    ->setCustomerId(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId())
    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->setStores(array(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()))
    ->save();

foreach ($rating as $ratingId => $optionId) {
    Mage::getModel('rating/rating')
    ->setRatingId($ratingId)
    ->setReviewId($review->getId())
    ->setCustomerId(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId())
    ->addOptionVote($optionId, $product->getId());
}
```

is called, but

```
$review->aggregate();
```

is not.  If I was going to approach fixing this, I'd add a cron job somewhere that built up a list of non-aggregated reviews, and then aggregated them.

Comment: Thank you!  We are actually inserting our reviews through the standard block.  I was actually using the aggregate data all wrong as I thought the aggregated options were per-review.  I ended up joining up with the rating_option_vote table and then averaging the review percents.  SOLVED!

Classic case of not knowing what I'm working with.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted — "not knowing what I'm working with" is Magento's bread and butter.

Comment: Haha thanks Alan.  I just realized who you were as well.  Props for all of the great reviews and blog-posts.  You've really helped guide me in the one year steep learning curve that Magento gracefully presents itself with.